# NoSuchMethodException with release Build

Tags: android

I have this code

```
String className = "namehere";
Class<?> someClass = Class.forname(className);
Object object = someClass.newInstance();
String methodname = "mymethod";
Method setSomething = object.getClass().getMethod(methodname);
String []ab = (String[]) setSomething.invoke(object);
```

Which is giving me an error in my releasebuild.

This is my error

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kryWerk [class java.lang.String, int]
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1981)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1637)
W/System.err:     at mypack.getWerkBl(werkData.java:171)
W/System.err:     at mypack.Werk.werk(Werk.java:618)
W/System.err:     at mypack.Werk$16.onItemClick(Werk.java:727)
W/System.err:     at    android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
W/System.err:     at     android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4036)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I First tried changing progaurd rules but that did nothing.

Comment: Please post the error log as well

Comment: Did you try -keep?

Comment: Please post the error log because it is not clear why you think it is from proguard.

Comment: try to disable proGuard in build.gradle: buildTypes {
        release
            { 
                useProguard false

Comment: "most likely" does not work here. Post your logcat to get the perfect solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with progaurd it seems..
I Fixed it by setting all my methods to Public!

Answer (score 2):

If you have this problem in release build, maybe it is because of `obfuscation` of your code. If it is not important for you to have your code obfuscated you can use `false` for `minifyEnabled` as follow

```
release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
```

so as the packagename and class name doesn't change , or use `-keep public class my.package.MyClass` to prevent this class which is loaded at runtime by `Class.forName`  from being obfuscated.

**UPDATE**

According to your error message, you need to change your `-keep` as follows:

```
 -keep public class my.package.MyClass {
    public void myMethod(android.content.Context, boolean);
    public java.lang.String myMethod1();
    //any other method that you want to call by Class.forName should be listed here
```

}

Comment: I have these settings by default. I have also tried the -keep. And it did not work. My error is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException but only in release build

Comment: @Darcia14 check the updated answer. If obfuscation is not the reason the please post the complete error log without eliminating any part of it (you can rename the package name and class names if you like to keep them private).

Comment: @Darcia14 As you have posted the error log (and it helps to focus on problem as it is instead of guessing what it can be), seems that there is a problem with the logic of your code. The method you are invoking, does't it have any argument? you have invoked it without  arguments.

Comment: The problem is, it works with debug build, but not with Release build